# Parse JSON and insert records

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class

I have this below JSON - In the below class i want to extract Contact and insert into contact object and accounts in account object.

Can anyone tell how to extract from JSON

```
{  
   "contact":{  
      "lastname":"Test Wonderland",
      "phone":"1234567890",
      "address":"BTM 2nd Stage",
      "city":"Bangalore",
      "role":"School Admin",
      "state":"Karnataka",
      "zipcode":"560076",
      "email":"test@gmail.com"
   },
   "accounts":[  
      {  
         "account":{  
            "Name":"School Test"
         },
         "quote":[  
            {  
               "gradelevel":"K1",
               "product":"Anmol P1",
               "quantity":"12",
               "price":"33",
               "totalprice":"396"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "account":{  
            "Name":"School Test1"
         },
         "quote":[  
            {  
               "gradelevel":"K2",
               "product":"Anmol P2",
               "quantity":"11",
               "price":"33",
               "totalprice":"363"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have created the below class -

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/CreateQuote/*')
global with sharing class restcontroller {

   public class Quote {
        public String gradelevel;
        public String product;
        public String quantity;
        public String price;
        public String totalprice;
    }

    public class Account {
        public String Name;
    }

    public class quotewrapper {
        public Contact contact;
        public List<Accounts> accounts;
    }

    public class Accounts {
        public Account account;
        public List<Quote> quote;
    }

    public class Contact {
        public String lastname;
        public String phone;
        public String address;
        public String MailingCity;
        public String role;
        public String state;
        public String zipcode;
        public String email;
    }
     @HttpPost
    global static String createNewQuote() {
    quotewrapper container = (quotewrapper)System.JSON.deserialize(
            RestContext.request.requestBody.tostring(), 
            quotewrapper.class);
    system.debug('container' + container.contact);
    Contact con = container.contact;
    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.lastname = container.contact.lastname;
    insert c;

        return null; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question you asked (and then deleted) yesterday. Like I asked yesterday, what exactly is the issue that you're facing? Your inner classes along with `JSON.deserialize()` should be doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way:

```
public class fromJSON{
public cls_contact contact;
public cls_accounts[] accounts;
class cls_contact {
    public String lastname; //Test Wonderland
    public String phone;    //1234567890
    public String address;  //BTM 2nd Stage
    public String city; //Bangalore
    public String role; //School Admin
    public String state;    //Karnataka
    public String zipcode;  //560076
    public String email;    //test@gmail.com
}
class cls_accounts {
    public cls_account account;
    public cls_quote[] quote;
}
class cls_account {
    public String Name; //School Test
}
class cls_quote {
    public String gradelevel;   //K1
    public String product;  //Anmol P1
    public String quantity; //12
    public String price;    //33
    public String totalprice;   //396
}
public static fromJSON parse(String json){
    return (fromJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(json, fromJSON.class);
}

static testMethod void testParse() {
    String json=        '{  '+
    '   "contact":{  '+
    '      "lastname":"Test Wonderland",'+
    '      "phone":"1234567890",'+
    '      "address":"BTM 2nd Stage",'+
    '      "city":"Bangalore",'+
    '      "role":"School Admin",'+
    '      "state":"Karnataka",'+
    '      "zipcode":"560076",'+
    '      "email":"test@gmail.com"'+
    '   },'+
    '   "accounts":[  '+
    '      {  '+
    '         "account":{  '+
    '            "Name":"School Test"'+
    '         },'+
    '         "quote":[  '+
    '            {  '+
    '               "gradelevel":"K1",'+
    '               "product":"Anmol P1",'+
    '               "quantity":"12",'+
    '               "price":"33",'+
    '               "totalprice":"396"'+
    '            }'+
    '         ]'+
    '      },'+
    '      {  '+
    '         "account":{  '+
    '            "Name":"School Test1"'+
    '         },'+
    '         "quote":[  '+
    '            {  '+
    '               "gradelevel":"K2",'+
    '               "product":"Anmol P2",'+
    '               "quantity":"11",'+
    '               "price":"33",'+
    '               "totalprice":"363"'+
    '            }'+
    '         ]'+
    '      }'+
    '   ]'+
    '}';
    fromJSON obj = parse(json);
    System.assert(obj != null);
   }
  }
```

now can extract any data from obj.

Comment: Hi Ram .. can u please let me know how to loop throgh to get contacts each field values..

Comment: obj.contact.lastname will give you the last name of contact which you can be assigned to your contact object the last name like 

    contact con =  new contact();
    con.lastName =   obj.contact.lastname;

Comment: Hi Ram.. in my above code which now i updated ...when i am trying to insert i am getting error ...DML requires SObject or SObject list type: restcontroller.Contact..

Comment: your welcome :)